# How to execute this prop as a function in the if/else statement?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I want to change the state in the redux reducer if GoogleMap DirectionService returns an error. 
How to use redux-thunk logic in the redux actions file if I use react-google-maps package and the app receiving data inside the component file that uses this package?

```
componentDidMount() { 
     const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     DirectionsService.route({
            //some state
          }, (result, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              this.setState({
                directions: {...result},
                markers: true
              })
            } else {
              this.props.HOW_TO_EXECUTE_THIS_PROP?;
            }
          });
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        HOW_TO_EXECUTE_THIS_PROP?: () => dispatch(actions.someAction()),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you will be able to simply call the prop method you're passing in. So if your code reads:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
         propToExecute: () => dispatch(actions.someAction()),
     }
}
```

... then you will call it inside your componentDidMount as:

```
this.props.propToExecute();
```

However, since we're using ES6, let's format it correctly, please:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     propToExecute: () => dispatch(actions.someAction())
})
```

Comment: I have tried this before, it doesn't work because of the async code, I guess.It shows  TypeError: _this.props.propToExecute is not a function

Comment: Can you post your whole file for review, please? Your mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps should be located inside a connect() method from react-redux, and your component should be the callback parameter.